# NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 73 for valid XML

Tags: xml, cocoa, unicode

The problem was:

I'm parsing an XML document which validates, but when I try to parse it using NSXMLParser, I get an error 73 (NSXMLParserGTRequiredError) before the didEndElement method gets called on the last tag.  There are some non-ASCII characters (degree symbols, specifically) which, if I replace with ASCII text ('deg', specifically), the parse goes through w/o error.  The XML comes from an external source, so I can't just change it; and even so, I'd like to know why this is causing a problem (and even better, how to address it!).

Here's an example of the problematic XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xml-status>
  <module path='P' title='T'>
    <reading status='100' path='temp' title='Temp' units='°'>98.6</reading>
  </module>
</xml-status>
```

Comment: Please add your answer as a real answer below and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could add a > to the end, and it would parse. Then looked at how I was PASSING the data to the parser, and saw that I was converting the string to an array of chars, but computing its length from the original string, hence the discrepancy in lengths.